# Motion 5 sharing projects in process with others who want to continue working on it

Tags: motion

I have a project in process where the mask has shifted.  I want a co worker to look at it and try to fix the issue.  When I shared it to dropbox, they could not open it in motion, I'm assuming because all the media files did not accompany it.  How do I do that so they can continue working on the project and all that I have done is not lost?